# Зачем нужны статические внутренние классы?

Tags: ооп, java

И когда их выгодно применять? Читал в википедии - так ничего и не понял.

Comment: сокрытие реализации. как пример Map.Entry и куча колекций в классе Collections

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Они имеют смысл в основном как средство тестирования/отладки.

Ну например: в классе может быть только 1 метод main() - точка входа/запуска. А если в вашем классе сделать несколько внутренних статических класса каждый со своим main():

```
public class My {
    public static class Test1 {
       public static void main(String[] args) {}
    }
    public static class Test2 {
       public static void main(String[] args) {}
    }
}
```

То у вас получится 2 точки входа:

```
java My$Test1
java My$Test2
```

оч. удобно. Ну и плюс сохраняется возможность доступа из внутреннего класса к приватным членам внешнего класса.

Comment: что-то ответ крайне не полный. В Хорстмане, к примеру говорится, об обработке событий внутренним классом, и об удобстве этого подхода. Будет здорово если вы более развернуто ответите.

Answer (score 0):

Внутренний класс делают статическим для разделения логики, чтобы он не имел прямого доступа к инстанс методам и полям внешнего класса(без создания объекта внешнего класса).